# getting the error - underlyingError: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" after SSL certificate change

Tags: ios, swift

We are hosting our apps on a container platform and we recently updated the domain SSL certificates on our platform for an app. Since then the apps are producing the error. We are more from the platform side and we have our clients reporting this error after the cert change.

```
underlyingError: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://myurl/api/public/registration/data/aggregated-data, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://myurl/api/public/registration/data/aggregated-data, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
   "LocalDataTask <B9717AA9-8363-4BDD-909C-73B664549298>.<90>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-73B664549298>.<90>, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled}
```

We believe its because of the SSL change and we rolled back to the original previous certificate and things started working again.
What we can see is , that with the new certificate we have a new root CA.
We saw many posts around this being caused by an SSL issue, and fixing the certs fixed the issue , but can we know what is the fix really ?
Must the client app be configured with the new CA (as trusted CA) for this to work ? Please note, that the new CA is a well known CA.
Also, we have only uploaded the server certificate and the intermediate CA on the platform, could it be that we must also update the root CA ? but we  had not uploaded the root CA even with the old certificate.(for which the apps are working)

Any help here will be appreciated.